# WPF Window closing confirmation in c# MEF context

Tags: c#, wpf, interface, window, mef

I am tasked with implementing a simple **confirmation dialog** for trying to **close the main window** of my application, but *only* while a specific process is running. Closing the application means aborting that process. If that process is not running no confirmation is needed.

At first I just created an interface to get **Application.Current.MainWindow** and used the **Closing** event of that, but my teacher came up with something else, I just can't find the right way to finish it.

There already is a **CanClose** method in the code base I use, which is empty by default. It's in the **AppInit** class where the MainWindow is opened. What I did in the **constructor** is this:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
    public AppInit(MainWindow mainWindow, [ImportMany] IEnumerable<IClosingValidator> closingValidator)
    {
        this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
        this.closingValidator = closingValidator;
    }
```

That was the idea of my teacher. Now in the CanClose method I can iterate through these closing validations and return true or false, like so:

```
public Boolean CanClose()
    {
        foreach (var validation in this.closingValidator)
        {
            var result = validation.CanClose();

            if (result == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The ClosingValidator currently looks like the following, which I think is wrong, but I need to build the dialog somewhere. The whole thing works, but the flag indicating whether the process in question is running is in the ViewModel of another project, meaning this confirmation dialog is always shown.

```
 [Export(typeof(IClosingValidator))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ClosingValidator : IClosingValidator
{
    private readonly IMessageDialog messageDialog;
    private readonly IOverlayEffect overlayEffect;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ClosingValidator(IMessageDialog messageDialog, IOverlayEffect overlayEffect)
    {
        this.messageDialog = messageDialog;
        this.overlayEffect = overlayEffect;
    }

    public Boolean CanClose()
    {
        using (this.overlayEffect.Apply())
        {
            var result = this.messageDialog.ShowDialog(
                new MessageDialogArgs(Resources.Resources.ConfirmClosingApplicationTitle,
                                      Resources.Resources.ConfirmClosingApplicationMessage,
                                      MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                                      MessageBoxImage.SystemQuestion));

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I think my question comes down to this:
***Where*** do I build my dialog and how do I use a **boolean flag** from the **ViewModel** to determine whether to show the dialog in the first place? I'm relatively new to MEF, so sorry anything's unclear.

**Edit**: I think the idea was that I can use that interface to implement further closing validations at some point in the future.

**EDIT 3:**

Simplified ViewModel implementation (The actual viewModel has too many parameters):

```
[Export]
public class TocViewModel
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public TocViewModel(MeasurementSequenceExecution measurementSequenceExecution)
    {
        this.measurementSequenceExecution = measurementSequenceExecution;
    }

        public Boolean CanApplicationClose
    {
        get { return !this.measurementSequenceExecution.IsMeasurementSequenceRunning; }
        set
        {
            this.measurementSequenceExecution.IsMeasurementSequenceRunning = !value;
        }
    }
```

The IClosingValidator implementation:

```
[Export(typeof(IClosingValidator))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ClosingValidator : IClosingValidator
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ClosingValidator()
    {
    }

    public Boolean CanApplicationClose { get; }
```

The IClosingValidator interface:

```
public interface IClosingValidator
{
    Boolean CanApplicationClose { get; }
}
```

The class handling the closing:

```
[Export(typeof(IApp))]
public class AppInit : IApp
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public AppInit(MainWindow mainWindow,
                   [ImportMany(typeof(IClosingValidator))] IEnumerable<IClosingValidator> closingValidatorClients,
                   IOverlayEffect overlayEffect,
                   IMessageDialog messageDialog)
    {
        this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
        this.closingValidatorClients = closingValidatorClients;
        this.overlayEffect = overlayEffect;
        this.messageDialog = messageDialog;
    }


    public Boolean CanClose()
    {
        if (this.closingValidatorClients != null)
        {
            foreach (var client in this.closingValidatorClients)
            {
                if (!client.CanApplicationClose)
                {
                    using (this.overlayEffect.Apply())
                    {
                        var result = this.messageDialog.ShowDialog(
                            new MessageDialogArgs(Resources.Resources.ConfirmClosingApplicationTitle,
                                                  Resources.Resources.ConfirmClosingApplicationMessage,
                                                  MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                                                  MessageBoxImage.SystemQuestion));

                        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

private readonly IEnumerable<IClosingValidator> closingValidatorClients;
    private readonly MainWindow mainWindow;
    private readonly IMessageDialog messageDialog;
    private readonly IOverlayEffect overlayEffect;
```

**UPDATE**
I made it work, the suggestion to Export the ViewModel with typeof(IClosingValidator) was right, I just had to add a second Export, not replace the default one, didn't know you could have 2 of them. So now with 2 ExportAttributes it works!

Comment: I have just recently started with prism and Unity, so i might not be the best person to advice you, but could maybe using events and delegates help you? raise an event that sets the boolean value whenever the process if started/ and another when it stops?

Comment: I already basically do that, the Boolean is a property in the class handling the process, but I don't know how to use its value for this interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your implementation of IClosingValidator is at the wrong place.
I have a similar project and what I do is the following:

I have a Interface like you IClosingValidator:

```
public interface IConfirmShellClosing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value that indicates whether the shell window can be closed.
    /// </summary>
    bool CanShellClose { get; }
}
```

This interface is implemented by all ViewModels which should be asked, if the shell can be closed. In your case all ViewModels where the process can be running should implement this interface. So each ViewModel for itself will implement the CanShellClose Property and decide if the process is running in this context. Only if all ViewModels return true for this, the Window can be closed.

Then, in your instance of the window, you can subscribe to the WindowClosing Event and ask all registered ViewModels, if the Window can be closed. This implementation goes to your ViewModel of the Window (or the code behind file):

```
[ImportMany(typeof(Lazy<IConfirmShellClosing>))]
private IEnumerable<Lazy<IConfirmShellClosing>> _confirmShellClosingClients;

    private void ExecuteWindowClosing(CancelEventArgs args)
        {
            if (_confirmShellClosingClients != null)
            {
                foreach (var client in _confirmShellClosingClients)
                {
                    if (!client.Value.CanShellClose)
                    {
                        // Show your Dialog here and handle the answer
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope this will help.

**EDIT:**

Okay, you still have a few mistakes in the implementation of your ViewModel and the Validator.

First of all, the Class ClosingValidator is not needed anymore. You want to give the responsibility to the ViewModels, and not to a central validator class.

After that, we need to change the ViewModel like this:

```
    [Export]
    public class TocViewModel : IClosingValidator
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public TocViewModel(MeasurementSequenceExecution measurementSequenceExecution)
        {
            this.measurementSequenceExecution = measurementSequenceExecution;
        }

            public Boolean CanApplicationClose
        {
            get { return !this.measurementSequenceExecution.IsMeasurementSequenceRunning; }
            set
            {
                this.measurementSequenceExecution.IsMeasurementSequenceRunning = !value;
            }
        }
```

What is happening now? The ViewModel implements the IClosingValidator Interface, so it has to implement the CanShellClose Property. In this property, you can define the logic, in which this ViewModel can decide if the Shell can be closed or not. If you ever add an other ViewModel, it can implement the interface as well and has a different logic for the closing.

In the Importing in the Application itself, all classes which are implementing the IClosingValidator interface are imported and then asked, if the porperty is true or false.

**EDIT 2:**

I have 3 .dll (HelpingProject, InterfaceProject and ViewModelProject) All 3 should be in the directory where the `compositionContainer` is searching. In my case, I built the container like this:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"C:\Projects\HelpingSolution\HelpingWpfProject\bin\Debug"));
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
```

So the Debug folder will be scanned to find matching exports. I would recommend you search for the this code in your codebase and have a look at where your container is looking for the exports. This does not have to be only one folder, but can also be a plugin folder or different locations. You can find a pretty good introduction [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/).

Comment: That absolutely makes sense, I think I was confused about the implementation. I will try this out and report back.

Comment: Ok so I think I'm at a point where it should work as you described, but I think the client I get is not the viewmodel in question, because when checking the clients CanClose property it's always false. I linked the CanClose property value to the property indicating the process is running, and used ImportMany as seen in my first code sample. Any idea why it's always false?

Comment: Just du make sure: I think false is the correct value, when the process is running? If the process is not running, than CanShellClose should return true. In case you are not sure if the property returns a correct value, try to always return true in the CanShellClose Property.

Comment: It always returns its default value, I think the list of clients does not get the instance of the viewmodel I use the interface in. I might have implemented it wrongly. Usually I get my interfaces via constructor parameter, but neither this way, nor when I use it directly (class : interface), it doesn't work.

Comment: My list of clients always contains exactly one item, which I think is the default implementation, meaning the ClosingValidator class, and the value of the property is what I define as the default value. The property in my viewmodel is set correctly, it's just not recognized.

Comment: Could you add your current implementation to the question? It is pretty difficult to help you without a shared codebase. One more suggestion: Did you add the [Export] attribute to the ViewModel? It could also depend on the PartCreationPolicy, if it is set to NonShared, every import will create a new Instance of the ViewModel.

Comment: I edited my post. The rest, especially the interface, looks pretty much exactly like what you posted, except for the Lazy initialization, which I have never used before.

Comment: Your ViewModel does not implement the IClosingValidator Interface, it is just trying to import it in the constructor. Is this due to the stripped down example, or did you miss it? The Lazy operator is used, to execute the import as soon as the items are needed, and not right at the instantiation of the class.

Comment: I thought this would implement the interface as well. But I have tried actually implementing it via ClassName : Interface, the property would be recognized, but the outcome is the same. Only one client, always false.

Comment: No, this imports an instance of this interface, implementing an interface is something different. Can you please provide the complete classes of the ViewModel, the interface and the Application, where you want to import the ViewModel?

Comment: I updated it, hope that's everything, it's just the one ViewModel right now needing this validation.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I updated my answer above. I hope this will help you to understand what is happening in the code.

Comment: Ok so I'm pretty sure I get what you try to explain, and I changed my code accordingly, but now there's 0 clients in my list. Does it matter that the AppInit class, the interface and the viewmodel are in 3 different Projects under one Solution? The references are working.

Comment: Some more suggestions: You could try to Export the ViewModel as typeOf(IClosingValidator). If that doesn't help, try to move the ImportMany from the Constructor to a private field and see what happens there. Just to make sure: How is the AppInit class instantiated? If you create the object by calling the constructor by yourself it is possible, that there is no import executed.

Comment: Exporting the viewmodel as IClosingValidator doesn't work, moving the ImportMany for some reason leads to the application just not starting, the AppInit class is exported as typeof(IApp), an Interface for application entry points.

Comment: Okay, I just tried to implement the complete example as I mentioned it above in a separate solution. In my case, the list of ViewModels was also empty. But this was only, because I did not have a reference from the App project to the library where the ViewModel is implemented. As a result of this, the .dll is not copied to the folder of the app and the compositionContainer of MEF can't find the exported ViewModel when trying to import the List. Did you check this? After I copied the .dll to the folder where my catalog is searching, everything works fine.

Comment: In my App project I have added a reference to the project containing the ViewModel, but nothing changes. Frankly I'm not sure where the compositionContainer actually searches, that logic is somewhere in the code base I use I think. Which .dll exactly did you copy?

Comment: I edited my answer. In my case there was no reference between HelpingProject and ViewModelProject, so i copied it by hand. I could also just have manipulated the container to also search the bin folder of the ViewModelProject.

Comment: I updated my post, I made it work, totally my oversight. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me, greatly appreciated!
And thanks for the additional work and the link, definitely have to increase my MEF knowledge..

Comment: Might be a completely new issue, but say I want to do something in my ViewModel before actually closing the Window but after the confirmation, would it be ugly to do that in the AppInit class?

Comment: I think this is a new Issue, but I would not recommend to implement this in the AppInit class. You could extend the Interface with a "forced Shutdown" method, which is called if the user chooses shut down in the dialog. But this discussion should be held in a different thread, I think. Glad I could help